# Event Structure Not Working Twice

Tags: labview

My event structure in the following part of my VI will work when I start up the program, but never again until I stop and restart.  I figure I'm not doing something simple, can someone help?

[image]

The event structure is in a while loop.  Again, it works once, but not after that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set **Enable Beeper** Value change action. It will occur once you change the value of the button from the front panel, or change the value trough property node with signaling. Changing value using a local variable or property node **value** property will not cause Event Handler to register the event.

Comment: So how do you suggest I fix the issue then?  I"m new to LabView so I"m not quite familiar with what you mean.

Comment: I think you should read event handler help and additional resources, anyway I will able to suggest if you send entire diagram, not just this part. And please describe what shoud it do

Comment: You can also use the property Value Signaling to activate the event remotely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your case structure is fine.

When you press "enable beeper" the event structure should execute the case you have shown and enter the case structure in the True frame.
When you press the button again, the event structure should be executed again this time processing the False frame of the case structure.
(I assume, since you have a local variable, that "enable beeper" is not latched).

If this is what you want to happen but not what's happening the issue could be somewhere else.

Is the Read from Visa function working properly? Could it be waiting for a reply from the hardware?

Comment: Yes the read VISA is working.  I put a string indicator on the front panel earlier to make sure.  It appears to just stop at the read though...

Comment: "Read vi is working" means you are receiving a reply form the device?  As @Khachik suggested, it would be useful to have a look to a larger portion of the block diagram.

Comment: Yes, I am receiving a reply back.

Comment: Can you provide the full Vi or a larger portion?

Comment: Believe it or not I found the issue.  I had a close panel event structure also in that while loop tied to the stop.  The .vi wasn't stopping so I didn't think that was the issue.  Took it out, but a standard control in and everything is working like a charm now.  I can provide a screenshot if anyone is curious as to what was going on. Thanks everyone for the help!